# How to use ancestry gem and active model serializer?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am trying to use `ancestry` gem with `active_model_serializer` gem but it looks like it does not work as it suppose. I tried some other answers on the internet but none of them work. I am doing it in this way:
Controller:

```
def index
  #render json: Nodepage.all , each_serializer: NodepageSerializer // It works for the first level of depth not for second and ..
  render json: Nodepage.arrange_serializable { |parent, children| NodepageSerializer.new(parent, children: children) }
end
```

Serializer:

```
class NodepageSerializer < ActiveModel::Serializer
 attributes :id, :title, :content, :folder, :ancestry, :children

def children
 self.object.children
end
end
```

This code produces an error like 'undefined method `model_name' for NodepageSerializer:Class`. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Try adding some more code like model and schema structure

Comment: There is nothing in my `model` but a line which says: `has_ancestry`.